# Shopify cartDiscountCodesUpdate storefront API cartid

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I want to apply discount coupon code to the cart page, I am trying to use the storefront API `cartDiscountCodesUpdate` which expect the cart id. How can I get this cart id. Here is what I tried. I have created the webhook `cart/create` which has payload `id` in the form of string something like '1eef2aa2c2b2e889ec325db72f0877ec'.

Then I tried calling this `id` which I got from `cart/create` response in storefront API `cartDiscountCodesUpdate` like:

```
 mutation cartDiscountCodesUpdate($cartId: ID!, $discountCodes: [String!]) {
  cartDiscountCodesUpdate(cartId: $cartId, discountCodes: $discountCodes) {
   cart {
     id
   }
   userErrors {
     field
     message
   }
  }
 }
```

Query Varialbe:
{
"cartId": "gid://shopify/Cart/1eef2aa2c2b2e889ec325db72f0877ec",
"discountCodes": [
"64J1ZQMBN9W5"
]
}

But its response with below error. I think its the issue with incorrect cart id. Can anyone help me how to get cart id after the cart is created?

Response from `cartDiscountCodesUpdate` storefront API.

```
 {
  "data": {
  "cartDiscountCodesUpdate": {
  "cart": null,
  "userErrors": [
    {
      "field": [
        "cartId"
      ],
      "message": "The specified cart does not exist."
    }
    ]
   }
  }
 }
```